# JS: Window location replace/assign/href ruins other functions?

Tags: window.location

For some reason, the following function is disabled;

```
function saveSubmit() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#loading-overlay').show();
    $('#loading-message').show();
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('loadinggif').src='/images/loadingbar.gif'", 10);
    $('#mainform').submit();
}
```

When I add this at the end:

```
var stringValue = window.localStorage.getItem("var"); 
window.location.href = '${baseUrl}/events/index.html?tab='+stringValue;
```

I've tried changing href to assign, replace, and so on, but the same thing keeps happening. I just need to make the page go to another page as if I clicked a link, tab or something.

Is there any other way to redirect that will guarantee that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location = '/somewhere/'` or `window.location.href = '/somewhere'` should work. Changing this property's value will force the browser to load the new path.

Have you tried `console.log('${baseUrl}/events/index.html?tab='+stringValue);` to check that the value of your new path is what you expect it to be? For example, I question the correctness of the `${baseUrl}` bit.

Comment: Fond out that the issue was in another place, but thank you for confirming this. (y)